# How to log exception thrown in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In my ASP.NET app, I have the following code:

```
catch(Exception e) {
  throw new Exception("error");
}
```

How can I modify this to log the text in the actual exception `e`?

Comment: You mean `e.Message`?

Comment: Most of the loggers allow you to log the exception obj itself right?